# Howto implement ICU MessageFormatter named arguments support from PHP 5.5 in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, icu, intl

In PHP < 5.5 there is no support for Intl MessageFormatter string having named arguments. 
With some languages and strings this leads to translation strings that are very hard to understand.

PHP 5.4 ( PHP < 5.5 )

```
$Formater = new MessageFormatter($locale, "{0} inhabit {1}.");

print $Formater->format(array('Wookies', 'Kashyyyk'));
```

vs. PHP 5.5 named arguments

```
$Formater = new MessageFormatter($locale, "{raceName} inhabit {planetName}.");

print $Formater->format(array('raceName'=>'Wookies', 'planetName=>'Kashyyyk'));
```

Our software has to support PHP versions ranging from 5.3 -> to latest but I'd like to make things easier for the translators.

Could anyone present a way to implement named arguments to MessageFormatter on PHP < 5.5?

Comment: I'm working on it for Yii2 framework but kinda stucked with string replacement now: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/pull/917/files#diff-0968cc0757071ec901e4c4dfac1145cdR20. The idea is to convert named arguments to positional ones.

Answer (score 0):

`pecl install intl-beta` worked for me, but that was almost year ago. Not sure how it is now.
May be simply `pecl install intl`